# C++ directory_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

It's been quite a while since I worked with C++, please pardon me for my newbie questions.

I wrote the following code to get a listing of the contents of a directory, which is working fine:

```
for (directory_iterator end, dir("./");
     dir != end; dir++) {
    std::cout << *dir << std::endl;
}
```

What does "*dir" return, a pointer a "char array", a pointer to a "string" object, or a pointer to "path" object?

I want to pass "*dir" (if it ends with .cpp) to another function(), which will act on it (asynchronously) at a later time.  I guessing I need to make a copy of "*dir".  I wrote the following code:

```
path *_path;
for (directory_iterator end, dir("./");
     dir != end; dir++) {
    _path = new path(*dir);
    if (_path->extension() == ".cpp") {
        function1(_path);    // function1() will free _path
    } else
        free(_path);
}
```

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator) it returns a directory_entry.

Comment: Cool, makes sense (to me).  I looked at the definition of "class path" (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path)  Can someone please point to me the constructor used to create "_path".  I mean, which of the constructor of "class path" takes "directory_entry".

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation of boost::directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator):

> The result of operator* on an end iterator is not defined. For any
>   other iterator value a const directory_entry& is returned.

Regarding the function call, I think the easiest way is:

```
using namespace boost::filesystem;

for (directory_iterator end, dir("./"); dir != end; dir++) {
  const boost::filesystem::path &this_path = dir->path();
  if (this_path.extension() == ".cpp") {
    function1(this_path); // Nothing to free
  } 
}
```

Where the function1 method can be declared as:

```
void function1(const boost::filesystem::path this_path);
```

Comment: Thank you for very much. In your code, What is exactly being passed to function1(), pointer to an object of type "path", or "object path", in which case the function1() will make a copy onto the stack?<br/>  The reason I ask, if a pointer to "path" is sent to function1(), will that pointer (object) be invalid once the for loop completes?

Comment: I updated the answer just before your comment. If the parameter is "boost::filesystem::path this_path", it performs a copy of the object.

Comment: Is that efficient, passing object as a parameter rather than a pointer to it, assuming in most cases we don't know (or care to know) the size of the object?  I am asking as a general programming style.

Comment: I think it depends on how you are using the object inside the function. Personally, I don't like allocating an object in one method and freeing it in other. In this case, the first path object can be a reference, so only one copy is created.

Comment: Callja:  I totally agree with you, as to allocating in one function (thread in my case) and freeing in another function (thread).  Following is my code flow, and that might shed some light as to my logic:(1) func1() finds file with certain properties, puts it in a queue.  Another function(thread) picks up this path from the queue and processes the file.  I figured the efficient way is to allocate a path in function1() , put int into queue, function2() picks it up,and later on frees it up.